# Fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxxx': Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: git, github, connection, clone, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repository from Gitlab using https (ssh also was used) but every time I try to clone, either the Jetbrains application or the Git app show the message with "connection was reset", I tried several possible solutions but nothing works:

- Reseting network
- Uninstalling Git and installing it again
- Disabling Firewall
- Deleting all my VPN applications
- Deselecting IPV6 in Network settings
- Reseting TCP/IP settings

I also have the GitHub desktop app and the issue is the same, so I assumed the problem is from my side in my network configuration settings or something related with that.

Sometimes I get the error: connection was reset by peer.

Does anyone have an idea what could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: to distinguish between "a problem with git" and "a network problem", use a basic non git client. For example : does `ssh -v git@gitlab.com` error ? if there is an error, what does it print ? (the standard command line ssh client has higher levels of verbosity with `-vv` and `-vvv`)

Comment: Hi, I realized that my antivirus was messing up with the whole process, after deactivating it I can clone most of my repositories. I'm still facing issues with cloning a private repository but is more an authentication problem (OAuth stuff) so I will create a new issue for that. Thanks for the helping anyway.