# Fatal: unable to access 'https://github.xxxx': Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: windows, git, github, kaspersky

I have the exact same issue as the person who asked this question: [Fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxxx': Send failure: Connection was reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74039512/fatal-unable-to-access-https-gitlab-xxxx-send-failure-connection-was-rese). They got it working again by disabling their antivirus.

When I attempt to execute `git push -u origin main` or `git fetch`, I encounter the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...': Send failure: Connection was reset.

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- disable everything in Kaspersky Total Security (all the "Essential Threat Protection", "Advanced Threat Protection", "Security Controls", and "Data Protection")
- reset my network and tried two different ones as well
- turn off IPv6 (restarted my computer as well)
- re-install Git
- create a new repository on GitHub
- use Bitbucket instead of GitHub
- uninstall Kaspersky VPN

Additionally, I executed the following commands sequentially:

```bash
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

However, none of these solutions have worked for me. I would greatly appreciate any further suggestions.

(Note: I refrained from commenting on the original question or providing an answer due to my insufficient reputation, as Stack Overflow advises against asking questions within answer sections.)

Comment: There could be a problem with the DNS resolution for GitHub's domain. Could you try using a different DNS server or flushing your DNS cache? If that doesn't work, could you provide more details about your environment (such as operating system, network setup, etc.)?

Comment: I'd also like more details on your network setup(s). Also, what's the rest of the message say?

Comment: @Winfried thanks a lot for the suggestions, but they did not work unfortunately. I tried flushing the dns cache with "ipconfig/flushdns" in command prompt, and also changed the dns server (IPv4; I disabled IPv6) to Google dns in the control panel (and restarted my PC), but I had the same behaviour.
I use Windows 10 OS, and I change a lot between different WiFi networks (public wifi, fiber wifi at home, portable mifi device, and somtimes mobile hotspot, but all of these give the same problem). Please say if you need more info. I am a noob when it comes to networks...

Comment: @JimRedmond that ("Fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxxx': Send failure: Connection was reset") is the only message I get in my git bash terminal when I type "git push -u origin main", unless I misunderstood you?